# Vlookup for row to column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

My table is something like below, currently I have a column as category with few types of cat names but now we what to have the categories as column header and the name's attached to it.

**Table now;**

ID | category   | Name |

856| Car        | Ford |

432| Motorcycle | Honda|

**Desired;**

ID| Car | Motorcycle |

856| Ford |  (blank) |

432 | (blank) |Honda  |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your "Table now" table is named `TableNow`, and your "Desired" table is named `TableDesired`. Put this formula into your `Car` column, and fill over.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP([@ID],TableNow,2,FALSE)=TableDesired[#Headers],VLOOKUP([@ID],TableNow,3,FALSE),"")
```